# Using NPM on Digitalocean NodeJS droplet fails

Tags: node.js, npm

I cloned my github repository onto a default NodeJS droplet on Digitalocean and everything works fine, I am running:

```
cd /my-project-directory
npm install
npm start
```

But I always get this error message: Imgur
The Digitalocean placeholder is already running in Node, I tried to kill the process but it always respawns before I can run npm start. How can I have my app run and be displayed when opening my-site.com in the browser?